# Using flexbox but it's not side by side on Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to position two elements side by side using flexbox, but on Google Chrome for Windows 10 it's not working.

**Prerequisites**

flexbox doesn't working.

**Expected value**

I want to use flexbox to align li tags horizontally.

**Reproduction procedure**

Run the code below, please.

```css
.header {
    .header__profile-button {
        img {
            width: 120px;
            height: 40px;
        }

    }
}

.header__nav {
    ul {
        display: flex;
        list-style: none;
    }
    li {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ポートフォリオサイト1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/css/header.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <a href="index.html" class="header__profile-button"><img src="image/logo.svg" alt="プロフィール"></a>
        <nav class="header__nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" class="header__nav_link">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="header__nav_link">Bicycle</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
<!-- Abbreviated below. -->
```

Comment: Can your reproduce in a snippet?

Comment: If you just take the two elements out of the list, they'll become side-by-side by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take your list items out of their list and place your flexbox CSS on your header_nav class:

```
.header__nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="header__nav">
        
     <a href="" class="header__nav_link">About</a>
     <a href="" class="header__nav_link">Bicycle</a>
        
 </nav>
```

Result:

```css
.header {
    .header__profile-button {
        img {
            width: 120px;
            height: 40px;
        }

    }
}

.header__nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
    ul {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        
    }
    li {
        display: block;
    }
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ポートフォリオサイト1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/css/header.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <a href="index.html" class="header__profile-button"><img src="image/logo.svg" alt="プロフィール"></a>
        <nav class="header__nav">
            
                <a href="" class="header__nav_link">About</a>
                <a href="" class="header__nav_link">Bicycle</a>
            
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main class="main">
        <div class="main__mainvisual">
            <img class="main__mainvisual-image" src="image/mainvisual (1).jpg" alt="メインビジュアル">
        </div>

        <div class="main__about">
            <p class="main__about-title">About</p>
            <img class="main__profile-icon-image"src="image/about.jpg" alt="プロフィールアイコン">
            <p class="main__name-text">Yusuke Oyama</p>
            <p class="main__introduction-text">
                初めまして。小山優輔と申します。
                KaiYコミュニティという開発コミュニティで、QAエンジニアをやっています。
                自転車と万年筆が大好きです。よろしくお願いいたします。
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="bicycle">
           <div class="bicycle__bicycle-image">
                <img src="image/bicycle1.jpg" alt="">
           </div> 
           <div class="bicycle__bicycle-image">
                <img src="image/bicycle2.jpg" alt="">
           </div>
           <div class="bicycle__bicycle-image">
                <img src="image/bicycle3.jpg" alt="">
           </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer class="footer">
        <p class="footer__text">
            ©2021 Yusuke Oyama
        </p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no need to write `flex-direction: row` when `display` is set to `flex` the `flex-direction` is set to `row` by default.

Comment: @AliMustafa that is true, i just like putting it

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the header__nav wrapping around the ul and li.

```css
.header {
  .header__profile-button {
    img {
      width: 120px;
      height: 40px;
    }
  }
}


ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  gap: 60px;
}

li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>ポートフォリオサイト1</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/css/header.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <a href="index.html" class="header__profile-button"><img src="image/logo.svg" alt="プロフィール"></a>
    <nav class="header_nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="" class="header__nav_link">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="header__nav_link">Bicycle</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main class="main">
    <div class="main__mainvisual">
      <img class="main__mainvisual-image" src="image/mainvisual (1).jpg" alt="メインビジュアル">
    </div>

    <div class="main__about">
      <p class="main__about-title">About</p>
      <img class="main__profile-icon-image" src="image/about.jpg" alt="プロフィールアイコン">
      <p class="main__name-text">Yusuke Oyama</p>
      <p class="main__introduction-text">
        初めまして。小山優輔と申します。 KaiYコミュニティという開発コミュニティで、QAエンジニアをやっています。 自転車と万年筆が大好きです。よろしくお願いいたします。
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="bicycle">
      <div class="bicycle__bicycle-image">
        <img src="image/bicycle1.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="bicycle__bicycle-image">
        <img src="image/bicycle2.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="bicycle__bicycle-image">
        <img src="image/bicycle3.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer class="footer">
    <p class="footer__text">
      ©2021 Yusuke Oyama
    </p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not working because your css is not targeting properly, you are using sass so your li should also go inside ul in your sass like

instead of this,

```
   .header__nav {
        ul {
            display: flex;
            list-style: none;
        }
        li {
            display: block;
        }
    }
```

use this, and it will work for sure.

```
  .header__nav {
        ul {
            display: flex;
            list-style: none;
    
            li {
               display: block;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS in your code:

```
.card {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.card .content-item {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="content-item">
            <p>What is Lorem Ipsum?</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="content-item">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```